# How to create conda environment with locally compiled python?

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

How should one create a new environment with a locally compiled/built python? All the information in the internet guides are about installing a python with a specific version, or installing local packages.

Any idea how to install a custom built python? Should I build a conda package and install it locally? (-c)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have to be built as a Conda package, otherwise other Conda packages will not respect it as satisfying the `python` dependency requirement. The [Conda Forge recipe for Python](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock) is licensed under BSD-3, so that may be a good starting point. It is a bit complicated, but not sure there is a way to make the compilation trivial.